# git - don't push commits merged from local branch

Tags: git

I'm trying to figure out a workflow for a shared repository that multiple people will push to.
The goal is to give people the ability to commit locally as often as they want to, retaining information on when they created and merged branches, while keeping a clean history on the branch they eventually push to.

With the man page for git-merge stating that `merge`

> ...will replay the changes made on the topic branch since it diverged from master (i.e., E) until its current commit (C) on top of master, and record the result in a new commit...

what I THOUGHT you could do is the following:

1. Clone repository, need to change something in branch `master`
2. Create a local branch `branch`, do all the work in say 5 commits
3. Merge the local branch back into `master` with the `--no-ff` switch, forcing the creation of a merge commit (which contains the changes of all merged commits).
4. Push that merge commit `master`

The local history I get when I do this looks like this:

```
* cada35b - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:55:45 +0100 (21 minutes ago) (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
|           6 - dev
* 8391544 - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:55:44 +0100 (21 minutes ago)
|           5 - dev
* 4381abd - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:55:41 +0100 (21 minutes ago)
|           4 - dev
*   40e21b1 - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:54:49 +0100 (22 minutes ago)
|\            #3254 Important Feature - Merge branch 'branch' - dev <-- Merge commit
| * 4f595e8 - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:54:38 +0100 (22 minutes ago) (branch)
| |           3.3 - dev
| * ea05ba7 - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:54:36 +0100 (22 minutes ago)
| |           3.2 - dev
| * d779583 - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:54:34 +0100 (22 minutes ago)
|/            3.1 - dev
* fab5a25 - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:54:20 +0100 (22 minutes ago)
|           3 - dev
* b6ddac3 - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:54:19 +0100 (23 minutes ago)
|           2 - dev
* 0abafad - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:54:18 +0100 (23 minutes ago)
            1 - dev
```

This is correct and what I want. What I would have expected (and need) on the remote is a history that looks like this:

```
* cada35b - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:55:45 +0100 (7 minutes ago) (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
|           6 - dev
* 8391544 - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:55:44 +0100 (7 minutes ago)
|           5 - dev
* 4381abd - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:55:41 +0100 (7 minutes ago)
|           4 - dev
* 40e21b1 - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:54:49 +0100 (8 minutes ago)
|            #3254 Important Feature - Merge branch 'branch' - dev <-- Merge commit
* fab5a25 - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:54:20 +0100 (9 minutes ago)
|           3 - dev
* b6ddac3 - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:54:19 +0100 (9 minutes ago)
|           2 - dev
* 0abafad - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:54:18 +0100 (9 minutes ago)
            1 - dev
```

However, what I actually get is all the commits I made locally, just without the branch pointer for the branch I didn't push:

```
* cada35b - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:55:45 +0100 (7 minutes ago) (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
|           6 - dev
* 8391544 - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:55:44 +0100 (7 minutes ago)
|           5 - dev
* 4381abd - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:55:41 +0100 (7 minutes ago)
|           4 - dev
*   40e21b1 - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:54:49 +0100 (8 minutes ago)
|\            #3254 Important Feature - Merge branch 'branch' - dev <-- Merge commit
| * 4f595e8 - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:54:38 +0100 (8 minutes ago)
| |           3.3 - dev
| * ea05ba7 - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:54:36 +0100 (8 minutes ago)
| |           3.2 - dev
| * d779583 - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:54:34 +0100 (8 minutes ago)
|/            3.1 - dev
* fab5a25 - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:54:20 +0100 (9 minutes ago)
|           3 - dev
* b6ddac3 - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:54:19 +0100 (9 minutes ago)
|           2 - dev
* 0abafad - Tue, 26 Feb 2019 08:54:18 +0100 (9 minutes ago)
            1 - dev
```

Is there any way to only push the merge commit and have it contain all the changes that were made on the local branch?
I am aware `merge --squash` and `rebase -i` exist, but with those you cannot see at what point something was merged back into a branch (`merge --squash`) or lose the local history entirely (`rebase -i`).

Comment: Which command did you use exactly? `git log ...`?

Comment: this is essentially the output of `git log --all --graph` excluding some formatting switches i use (which don't show up here anyway)

Comment: You cannot get different commit histories in local repo and on remote. If your local branch contains a merge commit, and you push that branch, the remote branch will also have a merge commit.

Comment: @Alderath That would be fine. What I don't want to see are the commits that don't belong to master, but those show up as well (see third listing). The branch I merged from does not exist on the remote, yet the commits that belong to it show up anyway.

Comment: That's because you merged them by doing `git merge`. That commit creates a merge commit with two parents. If you push your local branch which contains this two-parent-commit, your remote branch will inevitably also get the two-parent-commit. You could, as you mentioned, do `
git merge --squash`, this way, you'll be creating one commit which contains all changes made on the side branch, with only one parent (ie. you will be dropping the history of the side branch. You can choose one of these approaches, but you cannot have one of them on your local branch and the other on the remote branch.

Comment: However, if you go for the case with a two-parent-merge-commit, you could do `git log --first-parent` to list the commit log (on local or remote). This would skip the commits on the side branch, and would give the information you you desired in your second example. (The commits from the side branch are still there, but `--first-parent` argument makes the git log ignore those).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is *no, you can't get what you want here* and the reason is that Git is really all about *commits*, set in stone and saved forever,<sup>1</sup> in exactly the form they had when you made them.  This includes their commit graph linkages, because each commit links to its parent commits via their raw hash IDs.  The push and fetch operations in Git transfer these commits and include all the commits needed to make the graph complete.  The *names*—branch names especially—are largely unimportant and ephemeral, with one enormous exception.

The exception here is that in order to *remember and find* commits, Git needs the names.  The names locate the *end* of a graph chain.  From there, Git finds all the ancestor commits by following the graph.

Since a merge commit has two parents, and the graph must always be complete,<sup>2</sup> whichever Git *receives* the merge commit also gets all of its ancestors, i.e., both "sides" of the merge.  A commit that had only one parent would be a different commit, with a different hash ID.

That's the sort of thing that `git merge --squash` produces: a new, different commit with a different hash ID, but with the same *tree*—snapshot—that a real merge would produce.  But the side effect of using `git merge --squash` is that the development branch—the name you used in your argument to `git merge --squash`—is now essentially dead.  You don't *have* to kill it off, but you probably should.  Note that this, too, is OK: if that's what you want—if you want to kill off the development branch and *replace* the five (or however many) commits with a single commit—then `git merge --squash` is probably the way to go.

There's no single right work-flow here, but one possibility is for your developers to *not* merge their work *into* the next-level-up branch, but rather to merge the next-level-up branch into their work.  That is, I might begin with this:

```
...--o--o--*--...?  <-- origin/mainline
            \
             1--2--3--4--5   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

I started my `feature` branch from commit `*`, so my `feature` branch contains the five commits shown.  Meanwhile `mainline` may have grown.  So I run `git fetch` to update my `origin/mainline` and now I see:

```
...--o--o--*----o----o----A   <-- origin/mainline
            \
             1--2--3--4--5   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

At this point, I can, if I so choose, run `git merge origin/mainline` to create my new merge commit `M1` on `feature`:

```
...--o--o--*----o----o----A  <-- origin/mainline
            \              \
             1--2--3--4--5--M1   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

The snapshot in `M1` is the same as the snapshot I *would have* made, had I done `git checkout mainline` (creating my own `mainline` from `origin/mainline`) and then `git merge feature` and then `git push origin mainline` and then `git checkout feature` and `git branch -D mainline`.  But if I *had* done that I'd now have:

```
...--o--o--*----o---o---A--M2   <-- origin/mainline
            \             /
             1--2--3--4--5   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

Note that `M1` and `M2` have the same snapshot, the same author and committer, and the same parent hash IDs, but probably different time-stamps.  It's only the time-stamps that make `M1` and `M2` themselves different!  If I were to somehow do these two operations in parallel, in two different Git repositories, at *exactly the same time*, `M1` and `M2` would have the *same* hash, and—since the *graph* is the same—the only difference is the set of *labels*.  We can draw this situation more clearly by wobbling the graph nodes about a bit and just calling the merge `M`, and removing the two labels:

```
             o-----o-----A
            /             \
...--o--o--*               M
            \             /
             1--2--3--4--5
```

If we paste the label `mainline` or `origin/mainline` onto commit `A`, and the label `feature` onto commit `M`, we have situation #1: I merged mainline into feature.  If we paste the label `mainline` or `origin/mainline` onto commit `M`, and the label `feature` onto commit `5`, we have situation #2: I merged feature into mainline.

In other words, *both merges do exactly the same thing, except for the arrangement of the labels.*  So then, when I use `git push` to send the *commit graph* to the push-to repository at `origin`, *it doesn't matter which way I did the merge*.  The only thing that matters is what *label* I ask the Git at `origin` to use to remember commit `M`: do I ask it to set its `feature`, or do I ask it to set its `mainline`, or do I make up a third name such as `torek/feature`?

In *my* repository, I have *my* branch names (`feature`, `mainline` if I choose to keep one, `master` if I choose to keep that, and so on).  In your repository over on `origin`, you have *your* branch names.  We both share *commits*, and my Git remembers *your* branch names—as of my last fetch or push—under my `origin/whatever` names.

**The graph is shared.  The labels are per-repository.**  And that's (mostly) all there is to a repository: the graph and some labels.  It's up to whoever looks at the graph (and the labels) to guess what the intent is, and to work from there.  So you have to define your work-flows around these basic facts.  The `git push` command is going to send new commits that add to the graph, and then set some label(s) in the Git at `origin`.

If I do my merge into my `feature` I can then continue working like this:

```
...--o--o--*----o----o----A--o--o--o---B   <-- origin/mainline
            \              \            \
             1--2--3--4--5--M1--6--7--8--M2   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

My merge `M2` is, perhaps, easier than if I had not made `M1`, because my merge base for creating `M2` is commit `A` and my two tip commits are commits `8` and `B`.  When I made `M1` I had merge base `*` and branch tips `5` and `A`.  If `feature` is ultimately going to be squash-merged into `mainline`, with `feature` killed off and commits `1-2-3-4-5-M1-6-7-8-M2` forgotten and eventually garbage-collected, this is a reasonable way to go about the process.

---

<sup>1</sup>*Forever* is too strong.  Commits last while they can be *reached*.  The concept of reachability is pretty central to Git; see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).  Branch names—and tag names, and any other reference for that matter—serve to keep commits reachable.  Deleting a branch name may release its commits for Git's garbage collector to come along and collect, if they're not protected via some other name and its commit ancestry.

<sup>2</sup>Git makes an exception to the completeness rules for *shallow* repositories, but they don't actually help you here.  A shallow repository is one with one or more commits that *do* have some parent(s) with some hash IDs, but those parent commits are just *missing*.  There's a file named `.git/shallow` that contains the hash IDs of the commits whose parents are missing.  When Git is about to work with such a commit, instead of looking at its parent IDs, it notices that this commit is listed in `.git/shallow`, and for some purposes—such as `git log`—just pretends that the commit has *no* parents.  So this lets you, for space and/or time reasons, cut off the history of a commit, but it's just *cut off*, like a pruned tree limb, and later you'll graft it back on in place and everything will heal up and the graph will be complete—in all repositories everywhere, since the *commits* are shared and this one didn't change.